# How to communicate changes to static member variable between threads in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, static-members

I have a class that uses a static member variable as a flag.  The program is multithreaded, and changes to the value of the static variable are not communicated between threads consistently.

The code looks like:

MyClass.h file:

```
class MyClass 
{
private:
    void runLoop();
    static bool shutdownRequested;
};
```

MyClass.cpp file:

```
bool MyClass::shutdownRequested = false;  // static variable definition

void MyClass::runLoop()
{
    // much code omitted 

    if (isShutdownNecessary() && !shutdownRequested)
    {
        shutdownRequested = true;  // Race condition, but that's OK
        MyLog::Error("Service shutdown requested");
        // more code omitted
    }
}
```

I expected that the log line shown above would probably appear only once, but theoretically could appear as much as once per thread due to the race condition.  (The race condition is acceptable in my case.)  However, I see the log line appear dozens of times per thread.  I can tell because the MyLog class also logs thread ID, process ID, etc. for each log line.

So far, I have observed this problem only on a Windows release build.  I have not yet observed it on Windows debug builds, or with Linux builds.

I can understand seeing the log line once per thread due to different threads running on different cores on a multi-core processor.  I was surprised to see the same threads executing the log line over and over.

Can anybody shed light on specific mechanisms that could cause this to happen, and what I could do (e.g. synchronization) to force updates to the value of the static variable to be recognized?

Comment: Use [`std::atomic<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) instead of `bool` – problem solved. (The underlying problem is that you need a memory barrier.)

Comment: I should have mentioned: I cannot use Boost or recent additions to C++.  It has been mandated that I use Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: I cannot see any way that a thread could fail to see *its own changes* to a variable. So AFAICS you have have some **other problem**. Most probably in code you haven't shown.

Comment: @echawkes : Then your easiest bet (if you want to avoid locking) is to change the variable from a `bool` to a `LONG` and only ever access it using one of the [`InterlockedXXX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686360(v=vs.85).aspx#interlocked_functions) functions.

Comment: Just a question about your question. If different threads are running on different cores in your program doesn't this mean that each thread will have a different heap? If each program does have a different heap where will the static variable be stored? Is there anything going on with the static variable behind the scenes?

Comment: @Alf Your response seems perfectly reasonable; I can't understand why a thread would fail to see its own changes either.  My entire project has only the same four references to `shutdownRequested` as the code I posted, exactly as shown above, so I don't know what other problem I could have.

Comment: Is `MyLog::Error()` thread-safe? All the way down to whatever mechanism writes the log down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is **never** true that "the race is OK".  A data race, defined as a simultaneous write and read of an ordinary variable, is **undefined behavior** under every threading model I know (including Visual C++, POSIX threads, and C++11).

That said, since you mentioned you are using Visual C++, you can get away with declaring your shared variable "volatile".  [Microsoft's documentation says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd.aspx):

> When the /volatile:ms compiler option is used—by default when
>   architectures other than ARM are targeted—the compiler generates extra
>   code to maintain ordering among references to volatile objects in
>   addition to maintaining ordering to references to other global
>   objects. In particular:
>
> A write to a volatile object (also known as volatile write) has
>   Release semantics; that is, a reference to a global or static object
>   that occurs before a write to a volatile object in the instruction
>   sequence will occur before that volatile write in the compiled binary.
>
> A read of a volatile object (also known as volatile read) has Acquire
>   semantics; that is, a reference to a global or static object that
>   occurs after a read of volatile memory in the instruction sequence
>   will occur after that volatile read in the compiled binary.
>
> This enables volatile objects to be used for memory locks and releases
>   in multithreaded applications.

This at least makes the behavior well-defined.  You still have a race condition in the sense that multiple threads can all log the message, but it is not a "data race" in the "undefined behavior" sense.

As for why a thread might not "see its own updates", without synchronization a thread might "speculatively store" to the address for performance.  That is, the compiler might emit code like this:

```
bool tmp = shutdownRequested;
shutdownRequested = true;
if (isShutdownNecessary() && !tmp)
{
    MyLog::Error("Service shutdown requested");
    // more code omitted
}
else
    shutdownRequested = false;
```

This is a legal transformation for a single-threaded program as long as the compiler can prove that `isShutdownNecessary()` does not access `shutDownRequested`.  The compiler (or CPU) might believe this speculative version is faster.  But then in the multi-threaded case, it can result in the behavior you are seeing.  A disassembly would let you know for sure...

This sort of speculative execution, which tends to get more aggressive with every generation of compilers and CPUs, is one of the reasons "data races" very specifically invoke undefined behavior.  You just do not want go there if your code has any chance of living beyond next week.

The `volatile` declaration will prevent Visual Studio from making this kind of transformation.  But the only way to fix this across platforms is to do proper locking with a mutex (and possibly a condition variable if this is a busy loop).  The details for those differ between platforms prior to C++11.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation: that clarifies things quite a bit.  I thought that read/write operations on 32-bit aligned primitives (e.g. int, bool) were guaranteed to be atomic on the hardware we support, but perhaps I should not have assumed so.  (There is a lot of discussion of this issue on stackoverflow.)  I should have mentioned in the original post: my code is compiled on both Windows (VS 2008) and Linux (gcc 4.4.5), so I'll rewrite this code, putting the test and write of `shutdownRequested` within the same synchronized block.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution may be to just declare the variable as a static volatile bool. The volatile declaration will prevent the compiler from doing any kind of optimizations that cause the variable to be cached.

Answer (score 0):

you probably want a mutexed+shared variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you cant use any of the atomic features from boost nor C++11, then you could avoid a race conditions using a read/write lock. This should help reduce the locking contention that could occur with a mutex. A read/write lock is especially useful for your situation when you have many reads and occasional (few) writes, since there can be multiple simultaneous reads. As for writes, there can only be one at a time, which is also mutually exclusive with reads.

In Linux, read/write locks are available using a pthread_rwlock_t, and in windows here are two references:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa904937(v=vs.85).aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16411/Ultra-simple-C-Read-Write-Lock-Class-for-Windows